# Testing a service bus solution

Tags: testing, automation, servicebus

We are using Service bus for Windows Server in our project with various agents sending and receiving messages. Not all our agents are ready yet. We want to test if our agents are working right and are wondering if there is a way to automate it.

Basically, we are looking for an application that'll allow us provide information such as the message, service bus details, etc and it could tell us if the right agent picked it or not. It would be great if the tool allows configuring this data so it can be run from as a single-click.

Is there such a tool readily available?

Regards,
Shilpa

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your agents publish a message like "agent_ready" with all the information you need from them.